# How to add a washing machine drain to basement

Tags: plumbing, drain

I want to add a washing machine and a dryer to my basement. The main drain is at or below floor level. But I'm not sure how to tie into it. It's a cast iron.

[image: main drain]

It has a red cover, is there a way I can add a pipe here? The silver/grey pipe I'm thinking is an air line but it might be another drain.

[image: drain cover]

here is a wider shot.

[image: drain in basement]

Is there a connection for the cast iron/red covered pipe in the bottom that I can add a drain line to?

or does it make more sense to cut into the black pipe (PVC/ABS?) above and use a sump pump. That seems harder, but I think I can figure it out. Ideally, I would not want to use a sump pump.

Answer (score 3):

Do the sinks drain properly? If so, the easiest thing to do is to hook the drain hose of the washer over the sink. It's done in many washer installations and the sinks look quite big enough to stage the largest of water drains from large washers for draining.

Put a lint sock over the end of the washer hose to prevent clogs att eh sink drain.

No plumbing changes needed! :)

Comment: the sinks are not connected to water or drain but perhaps it would be the same idea to connect them.